# javax.xml.transform.Transformer swaps my elements

Tags: java, xml, xsd, transform

I have following XSD section

```
<xsd:complexType name="xyz">
<xsd:annotation>
 <xsd:appinfo>
    <Base ...../>
 </xsd:appinfo>
 </xsd:annotation>
 <xsd:simpleContent>
 <xsd:restriction base="niem-xsd:token">
    <xsd:enumeration value="Consumer">
       <xsd:annotation/>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="abc">
       <xsd:annotation/>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="s:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
```

I use `org.apache.ws.commons.schema` class to build it and after some time I retrieve it using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` class. When I transform it following is the result

```
<xsd:complexType name="xyz">
<xsd:annotation>
 <xsd:appinfo>
    <Base ...../>
 </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleContent>
 <xsd:restriction base="niem-xsd:token">
    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="s:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="Consumer">
       <xsd:annotation/>
     </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="abc">
       <xsd:annotation/>
     </xsd:enumeration>
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleContent>
```

The enumeration and `attributeGroup` elements are changed the position and that causes validation error. **Can I avoid this interchange in transformation ? What is going on there ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD format changed when transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347651/xsd-format-changed-when-transformation)